# Make Java calls from JNI during native signal handling

Tags: java, android, java-native-interface

I implement a custom POSIX signal handler
Ref : http://blog.httrack.com/blog/2013/08/23/catching-posix-signals-on-android/

Their appears to be a platform limitation with ART.

Is there a work around or any other way to achieve, calling java method from JNI through the signal handler method.

If not then is there an alternative scheme to catch the native crash and propagate to the app ?

Comment: You should not do this. Signal handlers should return as quickly as possible, not invoke JVMs.

Comment: I agree. Can you please suggest an alternative to achieve signal handling, where i can propagate the message to app ?

Answer (score 1):

First of all - you should be very carefully with what you doing in signal handler. Also there is a [list](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html) of functions that you can safely invoke from there, look for "Async-signal-safe functions". And surely you shouldn't invoke anything outside of that list or anythyng via `JNIEnv` because you don't know what JVM does under the hood.

As result there is no way to propagate error to the app. You can just write anything you want to some file with [write()](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/write.2.html) and then test this file at next launch.